# jQuery serialize checkboxes that are dynamically created from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization, checkbox

I create rows in a `HTML` table dynamically from `MySQL` values in a `PHP` loop. Each row represents a row in `MySQL` and are identified by an id.

I want to be able to have a `<input type='checkbox'>` on each row and have a "Delete selected rows" button at the bottom row.

My question is how I should `POST` the selected checkboxes and how to identify them in the `PHP`- file.

I have this script to `serialize` `<input type='text'>` fields:

```
function serealizeInputs (input)
    {
        var array = [];
        input.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
        return array;
    }
var value = serealizeInputs($('.my_input_field'));
```

How can I write a similar for checkboxes?

I'm quite new to this as you might see. Let me know if you need to see some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prop attribute](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check whether checkbox is checked or not. Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KS5uz/7/)

```
function serializeCheckboxes(input)
    {
        var array = [];
        input.each(function(){ 
            if($(this).prop("checked"))
            {
                array.push($(this).attr("id"))  
            }                
        });
        alert(array);
        return array;

    }​
```

Comment: Hello and thank's for your code. It seems to be close to what I want! However when the checboxes are populated they do not have the property "checked". Is there a way to recognize what checkboxes the user have checked?

Comment: It already checks that user have checked. Care if you are using older versions of jQuery(1.6), you cannot use prop attribute. You may try "$(this).attr("checked")"

Comment: Why not just use the `:checked` selector ? http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Yes, definetely :checked selector would be nicer.

Comment: @MehmetCanKamar The checkboxes are unchecked when created, the user should then choose wether to check them or not and based on value send a serialized string on what boxes have been checked.

Comment: @David if you are trying to do get checkboxes' string, you should use labels. Here demo is updated. http://jsfiddle.net/KS5uz/7/

Comment: @MehmetCanKamar Thank you, I found another solution but I'm sure your code would do the same job so I'll mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve all checked boxes, use the `:checked` selector http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

---

The common technique to manage this is to post the primary keys of each row to delete as an array using the array operator `[]`

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row) : ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="to_delete[]" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In your PHP code managing the deletion, the `to_delete` entry will be an array of string.

```
foreach ($_POST['to_delete'] as $rowId) {
    // Delete the row from database
}
```

Also, be unobtrusive ! Rely on a standard `<form>` element wrapping all your `<input>` elements. This will really simplify your JavaScript code, as you just need to call [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to retrieve an array of the checked boxes.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    // POST an AJAX request with data
    return false;
});
```